# Class MongoRegex() not found

Tags: php, regex, mongodb, lumen

I trying example from php.net:
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php

when performing a code there is a mistake:

> Class App\Http\Controllers\MongoRegex not found

But `new MongoClient()` work fine.

Comment: Post the actual code you tried. It seems it is missing the class, or it's not imported.

Comment: It says This extension is deprecated. Instead, the MongoDB extension should be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So now it would look like this:

```
new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex("/.*doe/i")
```

---

And if you're using Laravel with Jenssegers package in version 3+, then you can query like this:

```
User::where('name', 'regex', new \MongoDB\BSON\Regex("/.*doe/i"))->get();
```

or even better like this:

```
User::where('name', 'regexp', '/.*doe/i'))->get();
```

The line above will automatically convert string into proper Regex object.

---

Source: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

Answer (score 6):

`MongoRegex()` is for `mongo` extension and it not availables for `mongodb` extension. It seems you use `mongodb` extension. So you should use `MongoDB\BSON\Regex()` instead of `MongoRegex()`.

Comment: Oh when i look at your error message carefully, i find you have not import `MongoRegex`!
Please add this code at the top of your controller, after namespace:
use \MongoRegex;